# ']' expected when writing Blackjack method

Tags: java, blackjack

```
 while (hitOrStay.equalsIgnoreCase("hit"))
      {

        Card temp[hitOrStayCounter] = cardDeck.deal(); // issue occurs on this line
        System.out.println("You are delt a " + temp[hitOrStayCounter].getBJ()); 
        hitOrStayCounter++;
        System.out.println("Would you like to hit again?"); 
        hitOrStay = ketboard.next(); 
      }
```

Here is the segment of my code with the problem. I'm getting a problem where it says that it is expecting a ']', and I've tried to fix it to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
 public Card deal()
 {
    nextCard++;
    return deck[nextCard-1];
 }  
public static void main(String[] args)  
  {
   int hitOrStayCounter=5;
   Bankroll money = new Bankroll();
   Deck cardDeck = new Deck(); 
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
   System.out.println("Would you like to play?"); 
   String playGame = keyboard.next(); 
   while (playGame.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) 
   }
```

Also here is the specific error:

Error: ']' expected

Comment: Can you add in the parts where you define and initialize `temp` and `hitOrStayCounter`?

Comment: Also, what's the code for `cardDeck.deal()`?

Comment: I bet there is an compilation error in cardDeck.deal() (inside the deal() Method), we need the according source as SimplyPanda suggests.

Comment: Also also, did you mean to say "ketboard" instead of "keyboard"? Lastly, this seems like it might be homework -- if you're going to show it to an english-speaking professor, you might want to rethink the method name `getBJ`, as it has vulgar connotations in English (at least in American English).

Comment: Not to mention "dealt".

Comment: @JacobM I simply mistyped for ketboard. It is for a professor and he actually chose that method name. He's interesting. As far as the cardDeck.deal() i just added it above.

Comment: "it says that it is expecting a ']'" -- what is "it"?  compiler?  runtime?  program?  local cub scout troop?  Any time you have an error, POST THE ERROR.  And any time you write a question, assume we don't know what you're doing to start with.  You can also tell us what you have tried, so we don't tell you to try it again.

Comment: @JackMel please edit that code into your question so it is readable.

Comment: Where did you declare temp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to declare an array size in the array definition. The array size should be initialized on the right side of the equal sign. Based on my knowledge of blackjack, I can provide these suggestions:

- Use an ArrayList instead of an array. This should be done because an ArrayList can continue to expand while an array must be initialized to a specific size. This is needed since someone can hit as much as they want.
- Put the ArrayList outside of your while loop. By defining the variable inside the while loop, it gets overwritten with each iteration of the loop.

You can continue to use an array, but you should still declare and initialize it outside of the while loop. If you use an array, be sure to set a size that is large enough to handle multiple hits. You should use the following format if you continue to use an array:

`Card[] temp = new Card[x]`

Comment: If my answer helped resolve your issue, please click the checkmark next to my answer. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

try this. your loop is meaning less.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        do{   
          int hitOrStayCounter=5;
          Bankroll money = new Bankroll();
          Deck cardDeck = new Deck(); 
          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
          System.out.println("Would you like to play?"); 
          String playGame = keyboard.next(); 
        }while (playGame.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")); 
   }
```